# numpy assignment to dtype array of date with float causes 'could not convert string to float: '2017-01-01T01:01:01'' error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime, dtype

Why does the following numpy array assignment causes ValueError: 'could not convert string to float: '2017-01-01T01:01:01''

```
import numpy as np
r=['2017-01-01T01:01:01','61.380001068115234']
t = np.dtype([('d', 'datetime64[s]'), ('o', 'f4')])
s = np.array(r, dtype=t)
```

python 3.8.2 ,Windows 10, numpy 1.19.1.

Comment: try ``r=[('2017-01-01T01:01:01','61.380001068115234')]`` ?

Comment: With a compound dtype like `t`, the data, `r` has to be a tuple or list of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your data type to be a tuple of datetime and float, so each item in the array should be such a tuple.

This would be correct:

```
np.array([('2017-01-01T01:01:01', '61.380001068115234')], dtype=t)
```

If you had more than one item in the array, it would look like this:

```
np.array([
    ('2017-01-01T01:01:01', '61.380001068115234'),
    ('2017-01-02T01:01:01', '62.380001068115234'),
    ('2017-01-03T01:01:01', '63.380001068115234'),
    ], dtype=t)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I didn't realize it has to be a tuple. I was trying with a list all the time. You saved my day.